# Dialogflow Chatbot Load/Performance Testing

Tags: testing, dialogflow-es

I have been working on a chatbot on Dialogflow for an assignment of mine and my lecturer said I need to perform tests on the chatbot. I wanted to inquire if there were any way for me to test how many users the chatbot can handle at once? Would appreciate any help on this matter

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/best-practices#load), before deploying a chatbot code to production, performing **Load Testing** is advisable and three main points should be considered:

> Ramp up load. Your load test must ramp up the load applied to the Dialogflow service. The service is not designed to handle abrupt bursts of load, which are rarely experienced with real traffic. It takes time for the service to adjust to load demands, so ramp up the request rate slowly, until your test achieves the desired load.
>
> API calls are charged. You will be charged for API calls during a test, and the calls will be limited by project quota.
>
> Use test doubles.  You may not need to call the API during your load test. If the purpose of your load test is to determine how your system handles load, it is often best to use a test double in place of actual calls to the API. Your test double can simulate the behavior of the API under load.
>
> Use retries.   Your load test must perform retries with a backoff.

Load testing scenarios will depend on the pattern of your Agent actions. [This tutorial](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/testing-best-practices#integration_tests_2) in the documentation shows how to test a webhook fullfilment for spikes within the requests and soak testing ( constant number of requests):

- **Spike testing:** *constant number of requests and suddenly increase the load.*

```
ab -n 60 -c 60 -p ActionRequest.json -T 'application/json' https://example.com/webhookFunctionName
```

- **Soak testing:** *constant number of requests observing the responses.*

```
ab -t 120 -n 1200 -p ActionRequest.json -T 'application/json' https://example.com/webhookFunctionName
```

In addition to the information above, you should also have in mind the [Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas#table) for Dialogfdlow ES, for example the quota for Dialogflow ES text requests is 600 requests per minute (180 per minute for the trial version). Please check which one applies to you within the table in the linked documentation.